# Can anybody tell the code to import only selected data(rows and columns) from Excel to SQL through asp.net?

Tags: sql, asp.net, excel

[Like here if I want to import from row 5 and column C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXtLG.png)

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   String csvPath = Path.Combine( Server.MapPath("~/Files/") +        
   Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)); 
   FileUpload1.SaveAs(csvPath); 
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();            
   dt.Columns.AddRange(
       new DataColumn[3]{ 
           new DataColumn("KPI", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("KPIPN", typeof(string)), 
            new DataColumn("KPIPV", typeof(string))
            }); 
   string csvData = File.ReadAllText(csvPath);
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself? What problems did you encounter? You can't just ask someone else to provide you with working code.

Comment: i have done with importing whole data from csv file  to sql server,but could not just figure out how to give fixed path to the directory for uploading the file for  importing as well as importing only the selected rows .

Comment: heres my code , to import data from csv to sql without giving a fixed path to a directory + unable to upload only selected row .

Comment: protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String csvPath = Path.Combine( Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(csvPath);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("KPI", typeof(string)),new DataColumn("KPIPN", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("KPIPV", typeof(string))});
        string csvData = File.ReadAllText(csvPath);

Comment: foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\n'))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
            {
                dt.Rows.Add();
                int i = 0;
                foreach (string cell in row.Split(','))
                {
                    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell;
                    i++;
                }
            }

Comment: using (SqlBulkCopy sqlbulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
            {
                sqlbulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.csv";
                con.Open();
                sqlbulkcopy.WriteToServer(dt);

Comment: Please update your question with your code, it is not readable like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the LinqToExcel project

https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel

Comment: without passing any query!